# Yii Relational record with condition from other table

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I have a relational record similar to the following:

- There are users (table users) with ids
- There are categories (table categories) with id, name
- There are articles (table articles) with id, body, category_id
- Then there is a table read_articles with article_id, user_id

So a user can see a list of all articles in a category. They can click on an article and it will add an entry (user_id, article_id) to the read_articles table.

I want to be able to use Yii's ActiveRecord to get all articles from a given category that have not been read by the current user and display those.  I've been thinking about it in terms of SQL a little bit but I'm not sure how to fit it into my ActiveRecord setup.  My first idea was a parameterized scope on the Article active record:

```
public function unread( $userId )
{
    $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith( array(
        'alias' => 'articles',
        'condition' => 'not exists (SELECT * '
            . 'FROM user_read_articles '
            . 'WHERE articles.id=user_read_articles.article_id '
            . 'AND read_articles.user_id=' . (int)$userId
            . ')',
    ) );
}
```

It seems to be working, but it feels really dirty to me.

Is there a cleaner way to do what I'm talking about in ActiveRecord?  Or should I maybe consider moving toward more plain SQL and handling things like this myself (but lose a lot of nice feature of AR)?

**Edit** Here are the relations for the above-mentioned models: (Disclaimer, these are truncated to only relevant parts)

UserActiveRecord

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'categories' => array(
            self::HAS_MANY,
            'UserCategoryActiveRecord',
            'user_id' ),
        // I added this early using gii, never really used it...
        'readArticles' => array(
            self::HAS_MANY,
            'UserReadArticleActiveRecord',
            'user_id' ),
    );
}
```

UserCategoryActiveRecord

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'user' => array(
            self::BELONGS_TO,
            'UserActiveRecord',
            'user_id' ),
        'articles' => array(
            self::HAS_MANY,
            'ArticleActiveRecord',
            'category_id',
            'order' => 'articles.pub_date DESC' ),
    );
}
```

ArticleActiveRecord

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'category' => array(
            self::BELONGS_TO,
            'CategoryActiveRecord',
            'category_id' ),
    );
}
```

I have also made a "UserReadArticleActiveRecord" early as I was building this, but I never used that model and it is pretty much just empty.

In all honesty, I've been thinking of moving to Symfony2 and Doctrine anyway and just ditching active record altogether.  I know it doesn't solve this problem, but I might just drop this and keep my current solution for the time being.

Comment: Do you have a relation defined from Articles to UserReadArticles? If so, I'm pretty sure you can include the relation name somewhere in your named scope.

Comment: I could make UserReadArticles but I'm not sure I know how to fit it into a named scope.

Comment: show me the relations defined

Comment: it's added if that helps.  As an aside, would this problem be any easier with Doctrine 2, or just a little different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the **read** articles, you can define a MANY_MANY relationship on your User model as described here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

I don't think you'll need the proxy model UserReadArticles, you just need to define the relationship properly.

To get **unread** articles, I'm also having trouble thinking about the Yii way to do it, but a more efficient way than using a sub-select query is to do a LEFT JOIN to user_read_articles and check if a column from user_read_articles IS NULL (there was no matching row) something like this:

```
$this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith( array(
    'alias' => 'articles',
    'join' => 'LEFT JOIN user_read_articles ON articles.id=user_read_articles.article_id',
    'condition' => 'user_read_articles.article_id IS NULL',
) );
```