# Add relationship between two models

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I have model 1 represent a table with (id1,par1, para2 ) and model 2 represent a table with (id2,para3)

I want to modify model 1 in order when I use

```
$mydata = model1::model()->findBySql('SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id1 DESC');
```

this query return for me directly only where par1 > par3 (both of them are time), without adding the condition where . Or if thee is a method to add a condition where based in other model ?

```
  class model1 extends CActiveRecord
   {

public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

public function tableName()
  {
    return 'table1';
  } 
  }
```

Many thanks.

Comment: I tried to follow this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682674/yii-relational-record-with-condition-from-other-table?rq=1
but the two table that I have doesnt have any relationship, I use table2 just to store a value that I used as condition when I select
from table1

Comment: What is the exact SQL statement you want to execute including the condition for getting `par3`?

Comment: thanks topher, my query should be like this , select * from table_info where para1> para3 order by id1 desc. I dont know how to get par3 in the same query

Comment: Is `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE para1>(SELECT para3 FROM table2 WHERE id= some_id) ORDER BY id1 DESC` the query you want?

Comment: I can do like this when par3 belongs to another model ? because I get error in my sql statement

Comment: the error was , check your sql syntax

Comment: 'SELECT * FROM information_sensor  where sensor_id=   
     "'.$s['sensor_id'].'"  AND information_sensor_time > (SELECT 
     last_point_time FROM last_point where LastpointId=1)  ORDER BY 
 information_sensor_id DESC ';

Comment: I fixed teh first error , now I get "Trying to get property of non-object "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all comments, I solve it by using two cdbcreteria and make a condition between them 
[see my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763774/cdbcriteria-condition-from-another-cdbcriteria#comment20672639_14763774)